# Vs code terminal is blank and I can' t type in it

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I have this problem with my terminal: when I open it, it shows me a blank terminal and I can't even see the cursor. The windows is opening correctly and there is no error, but I can' type anything in the terminal.
Vs code version is 1.42.0
Also, I tried the compatibilty with Windows is set off
Here you can see what I'm talking about:
[screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6vGG.png)

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the right place for this issue. Have you had a look at the issue list or filed an issue with the VS Code folks? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: Are you using VSCode locally, or are you connected to a remote host?

Comment: I did not find anything helpful in GitHub

Comment: Yeah,I use vs code locally

Comment: Did you resolve this issue @SebastianWiton ???